# Fortify scan is giving JSON Injection issue for the code

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, httpresponse, fortify

I am using the following code for deserializing. But Fortify Scan is giving JSON Injection issue.

result is HttpResponseMessage object.

```
string re = null;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
{
    res = (string)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: This code is really weird anyway. You're getting the stream, then reading the stream to a string, then deserialising and forcing it into a string again?!

Comment: @DavidG I am not reading the stream to a string. Yes I am deserializing and forcing it into a string. Can you suggest a better approach for the same.

Comment: `stream.ReadToEnd()` will give you a string, it's not needed. But you are still casting to string, that makes no sense to me either.

Comment: @DavidG I was getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string' ", hence I cast to string.

Comment: Because its an object, not a string, you can't just cast it. If this code works, then I just assume it's a JObject and perhaps that has an explicit conversion to string. But that would just give you the raw JSON. So why bother deserialising in the first place?